# Android, GPS. Get location every second

Tags: android, gps, location, coordinates

I've this:

```
public class GpsUpdate extends Observable implements LocationListener  {

private int x_position;
private int y_position;
private float currentAccuracy;
public GpsUpdate(Observer observer){
    addObserver(observer);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
    setAccuracy(location.getAccuracy());
    setX_position(lat);
    setY_position(lng);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();



}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

public int getX_position() {
    return x_position;
}
public void setX_position(int x_position) {
    this.x_position = x_position;

}
public int getY_position() {
    return y_position;

}
public void setY_position(int y_position) {
    this.y_position = y_position;
}

public void setAccuracy(float currentAccuracy) {
    this.currentAccuracy = currentAccuracy;
}


public float getAccuracy(){
    return currentAccuracy;
}
```

}

this method (onLocationChanged()) notifies another method (update()) in other class that position is changed, but I need to collect all coordinates even that the current is the  same like previous.

```
_GPSUPDATE = new GpsUpdate(this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, _GPSUPDATE);

    @Override
        public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
            xCurrent = _GPSUPDATE.getX_position();
            yCurrent = _GPSUPDATE.getY_position();
                     .....
          }
```

So, what have I to add/change to get position every second?

Comment: so whats the question???

Comment: Why you want to kill users' battery that quick?

Comment: whatever ;] It can be every 10 seconds, but I need to get coordinates, even they are unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather bad approach. Even if you need to store location every second then redefine your app logic to store **timestamped** location. This suffices because (let's assume `T` is delta time in seconds) if at `T=0` you received and stored `locationA`, at `T=2` you received and stored `locationB` then if you want to know what location was at `T=1` then not seeing explicit record you know there was NO CHANGE of location at that time, so it is clear your location equals to last stored one with closest lower `T`, in this case at `T=1` your location (still) was `locationA` as it did NOT change since `T=0`. This is much better approach and would save you hell lot of storage. And if you store this in datbase then getting right results is trivial as well - just search for entry with timestamp **less or equal** to required, order by timestamp desc, limit 1.